# What happens if a property is assigned to a fallback and a default has not been specified?

Tags: javascript, ejs

Per the following JavaScript, what happens if a property is assigned to a fallback and a default has not been specified for the fallback?

JavaScript statement in question:
`options.content = options.content || '<div class="blue"></div>';`

The function the statement belongs to:

```
function NimbusCloud(options) {
    options.content = options.content || '<div class="blue"></div>';

    this._statusElement = null;
    this._statusTemplate = new EJS({
        cache: true,
        name: 'cloud.nimbus',
        url: '/static/clouds/templates/nimbus_cloud.ejs'
    });

    Cloud.call(this, options);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate found via [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing a variable to itself or to a value is a standard pre ES6 way of using defaults.

```
options.content = options.content || '<div class="blue"></div>';
```

The statement is translated to if `options.content` is not falsy (`undefined`, `null`, 0, `false`, empty string, etc...) , use `options.content`, if it is falsy use the default `'<div class="blue"></div>'`.

Answer (score 2):

This effectively provides a fallback default if options.content hasn't been set to anything else.